# how to get the first element of a list in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

My problem is not difficult :) i use **Laravel 4**, and i just want to get the first element of my list, my code is :

```
public function index()
{
    $userid = User::lists('id'); // here i want to get the first element of my list
    $services = User::find($userid)->service;
    $username = User::lists('username');

    return View::make('services.index',array('services'=> $services,'username'=>$username));
}
```

so if **someone** has any idea i will be very appreciative :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within Laravel, the 'lists' method returns an array. So, you may simply access the first object in the array by using something like:

```
$userid[0] = $firstUserId;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need the list but just the first item:

```
$user = User::first();

$userid = $user->id
$services = $user->service;
$username = $user->username;
```

Answer (score 0):

Get first item/instance

```
$user = User::first();
//or
$user = User::find(1); //by id
//or
$user = User::findOrFail(1); //it will throw an error

$user_id = $user->id;
$service = $user->service;
$username = $user->username;
```